# Remove 2d slice from 3d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, cube

I need to remove the last arrays from a 3D numpy cube. I have:

```
a = np.array(
[[[1,2,3],
 [4,5,6],
 [7,8,9]],

[[9,8,7],
 [6,5,4],
 [3,2,1]],

[[0,0,0],
 [0,0,0],
 [0,0,0]],

[[0,0,0],
 [0,0,0],
 [0,0,0]]])
```

How do I remove the arrays with zero sub-arrays like at the bottom side of the cube, using `np.delete`?

(I cannot simply remove all zero values, because there will be zeros in the data on the top side)

Comment: Did either of the posted solutions work for you? Any feedback on the solutions?

Answer (score 4):

For a 3D cube, you might check `all` against the last two axes

```
a = np.asarray(a)
a[~(a==0).all((2,1))]
```

---

```
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]],

       [[9, 8, 7],
        [6, 5, 4],
        [3, 2, 1]]])
```

Comment: If one is specifically looking for zeros, one could even do `a[a.any((2, 1))]`, since `0` is considered equivalent to `False`.  Makes the code a bit less readable for a negligible speedup though.

Answer (score 2):

If you know where they are already, the easiest thing to do is slice them off:

```
a[:-2]
```

Results in:

```
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]],

       [[9, 8, 7],
        [6, 5, 4],
        [3, 2, 1]]])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to remove trailing all zeros slices, as mentioned in the question that we want to keep the all zeros slices in the data on the top side -

```
a[:-(a==0).all((1,2))[::-1].argmin()]
```

Sample run -

```
In [80]: a
Out[80]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[9, 8, 7],
        [6, 5, 4],
        [3, 2, 1]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]])

In [81]: a[:-(a==0).all((1,2))[::-1].argmin()]
Out[81]: 
array([[[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[9, 8, 7],
        [6, 5, 4],
        [3, 2, 1]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

```
a_new=[] #Create a empty list
for item in a:
        if not (np.count_nonzero(item) == 0): #check if inner matrix is empty or not
            a_new.append(item) #appending to inner matrix to the list

a_new=np.array(a_new) #creating numpy matrix with removed zero elements
```

Output:

```
array([[[1, 2, 3],
        [4, 5, 6],
        [7, 8, 9]],

       [[9, 8, 7],
        [6, 5, 4],
        [3, 2, 1]]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use any and select :)

```
a=np.array([[[1,2,3],
 [4,5,6],
 [7,8,9]],

[[9,8,7],
 [6,5,4],
 [3,2,1]],

[[0,0,0],
 [0,0,0],
 [0,0,0]],

[[0,0,0],
 [0,0,0],
 [0,0,0]]])
a[a.any(axis=2).any(axis=1)]
```